# Postgres Error in pgAdmin : Invalid Input Syntax for Integer: ""

Tags: postgresql, view, limit

In converting from ms-sql to postgres I have problems with some views.

The error is : `Invalid Input Syntax for Integer: SQL state: 22P02""`

The problem seems to be due to the `"limit"` clause
If I select the view without the `"limit"` clause everything is fine
If I select the view with the `"limit"` clause, it fails.

In ms-sql everything works fine (top(1) <-> limit 1)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lew4c.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PdFn.png)

---

**The view is as follows**

```
SELECT ag."Codice" AS "Codice_anagen",
    ac."Codice" AS "Codice_anacli",
    ad."Codice" AS "Codice_anaditte",
    ag."AUID" AS "Codice_au",
    ag."Ragione_sociale_att",
    ac."Cliente_disatt" AS "Anacli_disattivato",
    COALESCE(ad."Ditta_disabilitata", 'X'::character varying) AS "Ditta_disabilitata",
        CASE
            WHEN COALESCE(ad."Data_Disabilitazione", '01/01/1900'::character varying)::text = '00/00/0000'::text THEN '01/01/1900'::character varying
            ELSE COALESCE(ad."Data_Disabilitazione", '01/01/1900'::character varying)
        END AS "Data_cessazione_come_ditta",
    ag."Partita_iva" AS ag_partita_iva,
    ag."Codice_fiscale" AS ag_codice_fiscale,
    "ANA_UN"."Partita_IVA" AS au_partita_iva,
    "ANA_UN"."Codice_Fiscale" AS au_codice_fiscale,
    COALESCE(( SELECT 'M'::text AS "Tipo"
           FROM dbo."MULTI_PRIVATI" mpp
          WHERE mpp."Anacli_disattivato"::text = 'N'::text AND mpp."Ditta_disabilitata"::text <> 'X'::text AND mpp."Codice_au"::text = ag."AUID"::text AND mpp."Codice_anagen"::text = ag."Codice"::text AND mpp."Codice_anacli"::text = ac."Codice"::text), 'P'::text)::character varying(2) AS tipocli,
    COALESCE(( SELECT COALESCE("ANAGEN_CRM".note, ''::character varying) AS "Note"
           FROM dbo."ANAGEN_CRM"
          WHERE "ANAGEN_CRM"."Codice"::text = ag."Codice"::text), ''::character varying) AS note
   FROM dbo."ANAGEN" ag
     JOIN dbo."ANACLI" ac ON ac."Codice_anagrafica_anagen"::integer = ag."Codice"::integer
     LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *
           FROM dbo."ANADITTE"
             JOIN dbo."ANADITTE_SINGLE_AUID" ON "ANADITTE"."AUID"::integer = "ANADITTE_SINGLE_AUID"."AUID"::integer AND "ANADITTE"."Codice"::integer = "ANADITTE_SINGLE_AUID".codice::integer) ad ON ad."AUID"::integer = ag."AUID"::integer
     JOIN dbo."ANA_UN" ON "ANA_UN"."ID"::integer = ag."AUID"::integer;
```

Anyone have any suggestions?
Thank you!

Stefano

Comment: In your view there is no `limit`, clause right?

Comment: The error is correct a `''` cannot be an integer.  Best guess one of your `::integer` casts is on a character field that has empty strings in it. FYI, this `'01/01/1900'::character` is not doing what you think it is, change the cast to `varchar` or `text` or don't the cast at all.

Comment: Why do you even cast so many columns to some type? And for all the integers used in the joins, did you create comparable indexes as well? Using the cast. If not, your next question will be something like "why is my query so slow". My advice would be to store all data in a proper data type and avoid unnecessary casting afterwards. That would also solve your current issue.

Comment: The final part of the original view in mssql is : ..... CAST(ad.AUID AS int) = CAST(ag.AUID AS int) INNER JOIN ANA_UN u ON CAST(u.ID AS int) = CAST(ag.AUID AS int)
Copying and pasting the view from mssql to pgadmin, an automatic conversion was done (I manually converted other stuff)
CAST( ... as int) -> ....::integer
But in mssql "select CAST('' as int) return 0" and then it gives no error
In postgres "select CAST('' as int) return ERROR : ERROR: Invalid input syntax for integer type: "" "
This different behavior is the cause of the problem
I changed the view

Thank you!!!
Stefano